Is the tensor product injective on pure quantum state vectors?
I am reading lecture notes on quantum information/computing, and the tensor product of two pure qubit states $|b_1\rangle\otimes |b_2\rangle\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$ was introduced as the "quantum analog" of a tuple of classical bit $(b_1,b_2)\in\mathbb{B}^2$. For this to be a sensible analogy, it seems to me that the tensor product should assign to  $|b_1\rangle\otimes |b_2\rangle$ a state in $\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$ which contains all the information captured by storing the states of $|b_1\rangle$ and $|b_2\rangle$ separately. For this to be the case, the tensor product should be injective on tuples of pure states; that is, there should be a left inverse of the tensor product which allows one the recover the individual pure states $|b_1\rangle$ and $|b_2\rangle$ that compose the joint state $|b_1\rangle\otimes |b_2\rangle$, similar to the way one can recover the individual bits $b_1$ and $b_2$ from $(b_1,b_2)$ by projecting. However, it is not clear to me from the way to tensor product is computed why injectivity holds:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_r \\
a_i
\end{pmatrix}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}
b_r \\
b_i 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_rb_r \\
a_rb_i\\
a_ib_r\\
a_ib_i 
\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}
It seems that the best one can do is recover the ratios $a_r/a_i$ and $b_r/b_i$ from this tensor product. Am I missing something?

Which lecture notes? Please give a precise reference.

I suspect you are trying to stretch the analogy further than it is intended in the notes.

As with so many things in quantum information, things get a lot easier when you consider density matrices instead of bras and kets.  For density matrices, there indeed exists an operator which acts as a left (resp. right) inverse on tensor product states, given by the partial trace: For any state $\rho\in\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$, we can define the partial trace over a subsystem (say, $\mathcal{H}_1$) as
$$
\text{Tr}_1\;\rho = \sum_{i=1}^d\left(\langle e_i\vert\otimes I_2\right)\rho\left(\vert e_i\rangle\otimes I_2 \right)
$$
where $d$ is the number of levels allowed in the quantum system described by $\mathcal{H}_1$ (in quantum information, it is usually $2$), $\vert e_i\rangle$ is a basis vector in $\Bbb C^d$ and $I_2$ is the identity on $\mathcal{H}_2$. It is easily verified that if $\rho = \rho_1\otimes\rho_2$, then $\text{Tr}_1\;\rho = \rho_2$ and vice versa.

The tensor product $a\otimes b$ of two vectors is equivalent to a tuple $(a,b)$ up to an equivalence relation $(a,b)\sim (\lambda a, \tfrac{1}{\lambda} b)$, where $\lambda\in \mathbb C$ (or whatever field the vector spaces are over).
Correspondingly, you can reconstruct $a$ and $b$ up to the same joint complex factor.
The better way to think of this correspondence is to only make it for the computational basis states of the qubits.
(Note that the "equivalence" between $a\otimes b$ and $(a,b)$ does not extend to the vector space structure of the resulting tensor product vs. direct sum spaces, so this analogy should be used with care.)
